# Combining 2 vlookup formulas in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need some helps.

I want to grab 2 columns, C (Net Close Qty) and T (Scrap Yield) from 12 sheets and match the values with respective Product Code. I'm using 2 different vlookup formulas for column C and T like this:

=VLOOKUP($A2:$A226,'01'!$A$2:$T$144,3,FALSE) for column C (Net Close Qty)
=VLOOKUP($A2:$A226,'01'!$A$2:$T$144,20,FALSE) for column T (Scrap Yield)

I have tried this code for only the first column

```
Sub Test()
    Dim lastRow As Long

    With Sheets("Summary")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("C2:C" & lastRow)
            .Formula = "=VLOOKUP($A2,'01'!$A$2:$T$144,3,FALSE)"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Is it possible to combine both formulas into one VBA? If it is possible, how to repeat these 2 formulas for every sheet? I have to do this by using Macro so that it can be automated. Hopefully someone can give me some ideas because I'm still learning. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop with a `Resize` method and a step counter:

```
Sub test()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim j As Byte

    j = 1

'// 3(space between columns) x 12(sheets) x 2(lookup columns in each sheet)
For i = 3 To ((3 * 12) * 2) Step 3
    With Sheets("Summary")
        With .Cells(2, i).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1, 1)
            .Formula = "=VLOOKUP($A2,'" & Format$(j, "00") & "'!$A$2:$T$144," & IIf(i Mod 6 = 3, 3, 20) & ",FALSE)"
            .value = .value
        End With
    End With

    j = j + 1
Next

End Sub
```

---

Note in your original code you get the last row from column D:

```
lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
```

As there is nothing in column D as per your screen shot I have used column A instead:

```
.Cells(.Rows.count, 1)
```